# git pull always shows this messages

Tags: git

I took a git pull and got this message Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

```
   1. etomsef/ui/portal/build/webpack.config.js  
   2.  etomsef/ui/portal/schema/msgs.properties
   3. etomsef/ui/portal/schema/schema.js

Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

I am using git for the first time , I get very much confused and more than the coding part , its git which takes time , often my folder gets corrupted and I have to clone everything again.

Above is the MSG i received every-now and then with different files, what should be the command I should run to avoid the confusion and rework.
I would have reverse the changes of this files taking backup and taken git pull and again pasted my changes is that the only option

Comment: Have u commited your changes everytime after coding?

Comment: No , but the files above mentioned are also files with my changes, yes i try to commit my code but it throws error commit not allowed , the msg shared above is the beginning , there is series of msg I get after following the steps mentioned by editor which leads to confusion and I have to do rework after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do commit/stash before taking pull like below & then take a `pull` from your `origin` or `upstream` branch:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git pull origin/upstream branch_name
```

or

```
git stash push -m "message"
git pull origin/upstream branch_name
git stash pop
```